# g++, ld and JNI - linking problem

Tags: java, linker, g++, java-native-interface, solaris

I have two 3rd party library files called libA.a and libB.a

They are built with g++.

Now, I need to do function calls from java using JNI.

I have a JNI wrapper file called wrapper.cpp and tried to created a library.so file which can be loaded into my java program and do function calls.

I first compiled wrapper.cpp using g++ and tried to link all object files using ld.

These are the commands I used.

```
%g++ wrapper.cpp -I /usr/java/include/ -I /usr/java/include/solaris/  libA.a  libB.a -L /lib/*.so -c
```

This created wrapper.o

```
%ld -L /usr/java/lib/ -L /lib/ -b wrapper.o libA.a  libB.a -o wrapper.so -m
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
_ZNKSsixEj                          wrapper.o
_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev             wrapper.o
_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev             wrapper.o
__gxx_personality_v0                wrapper.o
_ZNKSs4sizeEv                       wrapper.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to wrapper.so
```

Googling these errors does not help :(

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Note: I am using g++ 3.4.3 on SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding -lstdc++ to your linker command. You might also need --enable-auto-import.

Answer (score 0):

Using clang++.  -lstdc++ does not have the _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev symbol defined.  Try adding the library -lgnustl_shared to your linker command.  That worked for me.